# Piping output of `echo` to netcat fails while piping output of `printf` passes

Tags: bash, shell, netcat

I am sending a command to a [Teledyne LeCroy T3PS3000](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/teledyne-lecroy/T3PS3000/9598577) power supply device over TCP Ethernet using `netcat` (`nc`) on Linux Ubuntu 18.04 and 20.04. If I use `echo` the device fails to properly receive the command, but if I use `printf` it works fine. Why?

```bash
# Example command to Ethernet-connected digital power supply over TCP

# fails
echo 'measure:voltage? ch1' | timeout 0.2 nc 192.168.0.1 5025

# works
printf 'measure:voltage? ch1' | timeout 0.2 nc 192.168.0.1 5025
```

### References:

1. `timeout` cmd: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/492766/usage-of-nc-with-timeouts-in-ms/492796#492796

   1. Update/Note (written after I wrote the answer, so the `printf` form below is correct): without the `timeout` command, we would have to use the `-w` option with `netcat`, but it accepts only whole integer wait period timeouts in seconds, like this (notice the `-w 1` to set the 'w'ait period, or timeout, to 1 whole second):

      ```bash
      printf '%s' "my command to send" | nc -w1 192.168.0.1 5025
      ```
2. **[Teledyne LeCroy T3PS3000](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/teledyne-lecroy/T3PS3000/9598577) power supply**: from my [git & Linux cmds, help, tips & tricks - Gabriel.txt](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_dotfiles/blob/master/git%20%26%20Linux%20cmds%2C%20help%2C%20tips%20%26%20tricks%20-%20Gabriel.txt) document in my [eRCaGuy_dotfiles](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_dotfiles) repo:

   > 1. For help, contact:
   >    Teledyne LeCroy Support
   >    support@teledynelecroy.com
   >    700 Chestnut Ridge Road
   >    Chestnut Ridge, NY 10977
   >    (800) 553-2769 Option 3
   > 2. It's not in the manual, so I emailed them and they told me:
   >
   >    > The T3PS3000 uses socket communication and the default port is 5025.
   > 3. Manual (Quick Start Guide): http://cdn.teledynelecroy.com/files/manuals/t3ps3000-quick-start-guide.pdf
   >
   >    - p24, "Chapter 3 Remote Control" is where the command interface begins.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ugh! Found it.

### Ensure you're not accidentally sending a newline char (`\n`) at the end of the command

It looks like `echo` adds a trailing newline to the string, whereas `printf` does NOT, and this trailing newline character is interfering with the device's ability to parse the command. If I forcefully add it (a newline char, `\n`) to the end of the `printf` cmd, then it fails too--meaning the device will not respond to the command as expected:

```bash
# fails:
printf 'measure:voltage? ch1\n' | timeout 0.2 nc 192.168.0.1 9999
```

...and it looks like you can suppress the trailing newline from `echo` by using `-n`:

```bash
# works!
echo -n 'measure:voltage? ch1' | timeout 0.2 nc 192.168.0.1 9999

# also works, of course, as stated in the question
printf 'measure:voltage? ch1' | timeout 0.2 nc 192.168.0.1 9999
```

From `man echo`:

> ```
> -n     do not output the trailing newline
> ```

Key takeaway: use `printf` or `echo -n` to NOT have a trailing newline character at the end of your prints.

BUT, that's not the end of it! Here are two more points:

### 1. Don't use `echo` *at all* in any shell scripts if you want portable and expected behavior, and the ability to send *any* command to the device!

Using `echo` *at all* is actually a bad idea when trying to use it to send any possible string to the device! Why? Well, [@Jeff Schaller](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4957508/jeff-schaller) pointed out the following resource to me [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70001189/cmd-echoed-to-netcat-fails-while-cmd-printfed-to-netcat-passes#comment123749868_70001270), and it has *tons* of really valuable information: [Unix & Linux: Why is printf better than echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803/why-is-printf-better-than-echo/65819#65819).

**A few of the key reasons why NOT to use `echo` include:**

1. Its implementation, arguments, and behavior are all a bit hacky.
2. It is not portable: it has various implementations which differ widely across systems. Some support `-e` and `-n`, some don't. Some have the `-e` behaviors by default without `-e`. Etc.
3. It cannot print `-n` as a command, *at all* on some shells. See [my comment here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803/why-is-printf-better-than-echo/65819#comment1280533_65819).

   > On bash on Ubuntu 18.04 and 20.04, `echo "-n"` should output `-n`. Instead, it outputs nothing since it accepts that as the same thing as the `-n` flag. `echo -- "-n"` should solve that and output `-n`, but it doesn't. It outputs `-- -n` instead. I see your point very well now. `printf` is better.
4. As [@Charles Duffy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14122/charles-duffy) points out [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70001189/cmd-echoed-to-netcat-fails-while-cmd-printfed-to-netcat-passes#comment123756182_70001270): even [the POSIX specification for `echo`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html) recommends not using `echo` due to many of these inconsistencies and reasons:

   > It is not possible to use `echo` portably across all POSIX systems...
   >
   > New applications are encouraged to use `printf` instead of `echo`.

FYI, here are a couple key quotes from [Unix & Linux: Why is printf better than echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803/why-is-printf-better-than-echo/65819#65819):

Regarding `echo`:

> ...make sure that `$var` doesn't contain backslash characters and doesn't start with `-`

Regarding `printf`:

> But remember the first argument is the format, so shouldn't contain variable/uncontrolled data.

### 2. Use `printf` *properly* as `printf '%s' "my command string"`, NOT `printf "my command string"`

See more of the discussion in the comments below, between myself and @Charles Duffy. You should use `printf` like this instead:

```bash
# CORRECT USAGE: >>> FINAL ANSWER; DO THIS! <<<
printf '%s' 'measure:voltage? ch1' | timeout 0.2 nc 192.168.0.1 9999  

# NOT this:
printf 'measure:voltage? ch1' | timeout 0.2 nc 192.168.0.1 9999
```

This is because the first argument passed to `printf` is parsed as the *format string*. If the command string you're trying to send to the device is `%s`, for instance, this doesn't send anything!:

```bash
printf "%s"
```

The output is empty since `printf` interprets the first argument as a format string, and `%s` means something special in format strings. But this does send the `%s` as a literal:

```bash
printf "%s" "%s"
```

The output is

> ```
> %s
> ```

The first `"%s"` in the arguments to `printf` is the *format string*, and the second `"s"` is the *string literal* to substitute into the format string where the first `%s` lies, according to the `printf` specification.

**This means that the correct usage of `printf` will be able to send ANY command to the device, whereas the incorrect usage will strip out any formatting chars such as `%s`, `%02X`, `%u`, etc etc--any of the [`printf`-style format string special chars or sequences](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/).**

### See also:

1. [Unix & Linux: Why is printf better than echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803/why-is-printf-better-than-echo/65819#65819)
2. [the POSIX specification for `echo`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html)
3. My netcat tutorial: [ServerFault: General netcat (`nc`) usage instructions, including setting the IP address to bind to when receiving, or to send to when sending](https://serverfault.com/a/1140509/357116)

Comment: For even more background (beware various implementations of `echo` and "So what that means is that you can't use echo to display uncontrolled data"): https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803/why-is-printf-better-than-echo

Comment: `echo -n` is unreliable -- even the [POSIX specification for `echo`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html) tells you this. (The [unix.se] link above goes into even more detail).

Comment: BTW, it's more reliable to use `printf '%s' "string"` than `printf "string"`, because the former forces the string to be treated as a literal rather than a format string.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, can you expound upon your last statement? How is "forc[ing] the string to be treated as a literal" a bad thing?

Comment: @GabrielStaples, it's a _good_ thing, which is why I recommend `printf '%s' "string"` instead of `printf string`.

Comment: ...otherwise if your string has `%`s, backslashes, or anything else that's special in a format string it'll be written in a format that doesn't match how it was given.

Comment: (...even for format strings with backslash-escape sequences, `printf '%b' "string"` -- or, if they should have a trailing newline, `printf '%b\n' "string"` -- is safer than `printf "string"`, since it means you get your backslash sigils processed, but prevents `%`s from being unintentionally treated as special).

Comment: Oh, right. I get it. If the string I'm trying to send is `%s`, for instance, this doesn't send _anything_!: `printf "%s"`. The output is empty since `printf` interprets the first argument as a format string, and `%s` means something special in format strings. But this _does_ send my `%s` as a literal: `printf "%s" "%s"`. The output is `%s`. I'll update my answer with this new information.

Comment: is there any difference between '%s' and "%s" in this context? (they seem to be used interchangeably in the answer)

Comment: @shea, in this context they are interchangeable. Just remember that in Bash, double quotes (`" "`) allow variable substitution within them, and single quotes (`' ' `) do not.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that netcat on Ubuntu 18.04 changed, you can use "netcat -N" to complete the transaction.